# Making changes to lexer while parsing

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse N3 using ANTLR4;

In pseudo-ANTLR:

```
{plain_is = plain_of = false}

document : (keywords | triple)* ;
keywords : '@keywords' NCNAME (',' NCNAME)* '.'
  {plain_is = 'is' in ncnames
   plain_of = 'of' in ncnames} ;
triple : value predicate value '.' ;
predicate : value | KW_IS value KW_OF ;
value : QNAME | NCNAME ;
QNAME : [a-z]* ':' [a-z]+
NCNAME : [a-z]+ ;
KW_IS : {plain_is}? 'is' | {!plain_is}? '@is' ;
KW_OF : {plain_of}? 'of' | {!plain_of}? '@of' ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Ignoring the `@keywords` semantics for now, this is a valid document:

```
:x :y :z.
:z is :y of :z.
```

But if `@keywords` is used, all keywords not specified in the list must be prefixed with `@`, which allows using them as `NCNAME`s:

```
@keywords is.
:z is :y @of of.
```

Is there a way to describe this in ANTLR? i.e. after parsing the `keywords` production, pass some flags (like `plain_is`) back to the lexer?

Currently I'm using a permissive grammar and check after parsing, converting the non-listed keywords back to `NCNAME`s.

Comment: {plain_is} should be {plain_is}? right?

Comment: yes, if the parser & lexer were the same thing, this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser does not have the ability to change the operation of the lexer.  Although initiated by the parser, The lexer will process the entire input stream before the parser begins its evaluation of the parser rules.

You may be looking for lexer 'modes', aka [lexical modes](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexicalModes).

Comment: Unfortunately the lexer modes don't seem to be flexible enough, instead of a mode stack I'd need flag bits...

Comment: I had hoped the lexer would be lazy enough to only consume as many tokens as needed.

Comment: you can put actions and predicates in the lexer to do what you want possibly in conjunction with modes.

Comment: Great! I was somehow under the impression that the lexer didn't allow this, but I found the `actions/Keywords.g4` sample, by moving my `@keywords` production to the lexer I can manage a map like that dynamically